# 'System.Collections.Generic' best choice for a list of username and passwords

Tags: c#, string, collections

I have a set of username/password pairs. There are no duplicate usernames but passwords duplication is allowed.

Using `System.Collections` I have many choices for example:

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> accounts;

// or

System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection[] accounts;
```

All of us have the concepts of what a programmer needs with a set of username/password pair (get password of a known username, add a username/password ...).

Comment: This is a two level collection. A collection for a username/password pair and a collection for these pairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> accounts
```

The type `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` was part of the first version of .NET, before generics were available. It is better to use a generic collection where possible.

I'd also advise you *not* to store the passwords in plain text, in case that's what you are doing.

Comment: I don't want this. I told there's no constraint for password uniqueness. There is always a single password for a given username.

Comment: If you have a unique Username, use it as the key - or am I missing something?

Comment: @Xaqron The values in Dictionary generic don't need to be unique.  Only the keys in Dictionary are unique

Comment: @Mark: and for a collection of username/password pairs use `Dictionary<Dictionary<string, string>>` or `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` ?

Comment: @Xaqron: No, use Dictionary<string, string> as per my answer. A dictionary is a collection already.

Comment: @Xaqron: I think you are confusing `Dictionary<string, string>` with `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Answer (score 2):

I think I would simply use

```
Dictionary<string, SecureString>
```

The keys in dictionary are unqiue.  You can add/remove new user to your dictionary.  You can lookup/change password from dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want a [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with using just a `Dictionary<string, string>`? It would allow you to do whatever you need. (Or maybe `SortedDictionary<string, string>` or `SortedList<string, string>` if you need fast retrieval)